# Is it possible to compile Emscripten as easily as now, but without the console and emscripten logo?

Tags: c++, compilation, frontend, emscripten

When compiling C++ with emscripten without any parameters, it generates an html file with console and emscripten logo, besides the webgl canvas.

Is it possible to disable the logo\console and just have it generate html\js for a blank webpage filled with the webgl canvas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `emcc --shell-file <path>`

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html