# How to get rid of emscripten logo and console while only having a canvas?

Tags: javascript, c, sdl, webassembly, emscripten

Whenever I compile my C code with `emcc main.c -o index.html` emscripten generates an html file with their logo and some buttons and the console. But I don't want those. I only want the canvas where I can show my SDL rendered stuff.

I did a little bit of research and found [this question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407924/is-it-possible-to-compile-emscripten-as-easily-as-now-but-without-the-console-a/36419037). Apparently you have to enter `emcc --shell-file` and give it some template html as an argument.

So I made a template html file like so

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Some title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

But when I ran `emcc main.c -o index.html --shell-file template.html` it gave an error. Apparently emscripten looks for some think like - `{{{ SCRIPT }}}`.

So I added `{{{ SCRIPT }}}` inside my body. It compiled fine. But when I ran my `index.html` in `localhost:3000` I got an error in the console which said `cannot find addEventListener of undefined`.

[N.B. I am running an SDL program. [The one mentioned in their docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#generating-html)

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you find the default template file and edit that one?

Comment: I looked inside that file and it seemed like a huge mess to me. Sure, I could slowly read what each of the tags are doing, but it just does not feel like the right way to solve my problem. I am looking for an easier way, or an already built template without the logo and all (which I didn't find anywhere)

Comment: Perhaps shell_minimal.html is that one. https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/src/shell_minimal.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/timhutton/sdl-canvas-wasm/blob/main/index.html) is a minimal example that you can use as your `index.html`, assuming your canvas code is in `index.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Create the canvas that the C++ code will draw into -->
    <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>

    <!-- Allow the C++ to access the canvas element --> 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var Module = {
            canvas: (function() { return document.getElementById('canvas'); })()
        };
    </script>
    
    <!-- Add the javascript glue code (index.js) as generated by Emscripten -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```